# How to deploy pure html to Octopress?

Tags: github-pages, octopress

I am using Octopress to write posts, which uses markdown file to generate html files, using :

```
rake new_post['my_post']
rake generate
```

But what if I need to add some JavaScript demo inside my post, which I need to write some code inside the post, which may possibly be a html page I am writing as.

Can I achieve this with Octopress and remain overall consistency of style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your Javascript block into its own HTML file, in your `source/_includes/` directory. Then you can embed that into your post using Liquid include tags:

```
---
layout: post
title: "JS Demo"
date: 2015-01-01 01:01:01
categories: 
---

{% include myjs.html %}
```

and the contents of `myjs.html` would be:

```
<div id="myelement"></div>

<script>
$('div#myelement').text("hello world");
</script>
```

and `myjs.html` would be at `source/_includes/myjs.html`. Then your final page source code would (for example) render as:

```
<div><h1>JS Demo</h1></div>
<div id="myelement">hello world</div>
```

If you want to structure the Javascript code you're including a bit more, you can make a directory for Javascript files in (e.g.) `source/_includes/demo/`, then put your Javascript into `source/_includes/demo.html`. Then your markdown would have the following Liquid include tags:

```
{% include demo/demo.html %}
```

Comment: How can  I post a myjs.html? I am writing .markdown and use `rake generate ` to generate .html file.

Comment: You literally plop the include code into your post's markdown. As long as myjs.html is in your `source/_includes` directory, and has an html extension, it'll get included as verbatim html code.

Comment: For example, if I am writing a markdown with a title "
## JS DEMO ##", and I need to show a "hello world from myjs.html"  after that title, how should I write the myjs.html . I mean without knowing the dom elment of the title "JS DEMO", how can I create a dom element and insert it into the right place?

Comment: You can add the `{% include _includes/myjs.html %}` tags right after your title. Then, in `myjs.html`, you would have your Javascript code in `<source>` tags. If you need to have a DOM element to modify, you can add `<div id="myelement"></div>` to `myjs.html`, right before you put your Javascript `<source>` tags.

Comment: Unless you're trying to modify the DOM of the post title itself. If that's the case, you can modify your Octopress theme, and add a custom id attribute to whatever tag you want to modify. Then, when it prints the title, it would look like `<div id="mytitle"><h2>JS DEMO</h2></div>` and then you could grab the `div#mytitle` element from your Javascript code.

Comment: Yes, you got it. If you're not sure how to write a hello world program in javascript, that's a whole different question and I'd suggest opening a separate thread.

Comment: Say I am only need to print hello world after the title, how shoud I organize the markdown file and myhs,html?   I know how to operate on dom, say if I am using jquery, I know the id of the title is title1, i will do like : $('#title').append($("<div>hello world<div>')). But now the problem is I do not know the id(or class to have the selector), to append my new dom element to. Would you please update your answer to show a case like this?

Comment: if you're printing hello world *after* the title, and not *modifying* the title, why are you getting the title tag? just add your own div element and add hello world to it. I've updated my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Works! But the path does not work for me. I put a demo1.html inside /_includes/demo , and the path `{% include demo/demo1.html %}` works for me, would you please check your answer and updated it? I will accept it after that.